# Haskell throws an error while specifying the type of a parameter

Tags: haskell, ghci

I just started learning Haskell. I'm trying to implement a function which takes a number as it's input, and return -1, 0 or 1 depending on it's value. The input can be any number (integer or a floating point). Here is the code:

```
signum :: (Num a) => a -> Int
signum x
    | x > 0 = 1
    | x < 0 = -1
    | otherwise = 0
```

But when I try to load it into **ghci**, it shows the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( run_it.hs, interpreted )

run_it.hs:7:13:
Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of `>'
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for Main.signum :: Num a => a -> Int
  at run_it.hs:5:11-29
Possible fix:
  add (Ord a) to the context of
    the type signature for Main.signum :: Num a => a -> Int
In the expression: x > 0
In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for `signum':
  x > 0
In an equation for `signum':
    signum x
      | x > 0 = 1
      | x < 0 = - 1
      | otherwise = 0
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: `Num` does not derive `Ord` in haskell. So you can not use `>` and `<` operators on members of `Num` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `>` is defined in the `Ord` class, so you need to add an additional constraint to your type signature:

```
signum :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Int
```

In GHCi, you can view the methods of a class with `:i <Class>`, for example:

```
*Main> :i Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  [...]
```

Alternatively, you can check the method itself:

```
*Main> :i (>)
class Eq a => Ord a where
  ...
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
infix 4 >
```

The reason why the original `signum` doesn't have this constraint is because it doesn't use the methods from `Ord`.  Instead, it uses functions specialized to a type in question (like `ltInt`) or pattern matches directly (see the `Word` instance): https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Num.html#signum

Comment: Thank u very much for helping :-)
I'm fairly new to haskell, and these error messages are very cryptic for me to make sense of them !!!